# I need a function which describes the following behaviour

Tags: functions

The table of keys and values is (approximately):
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline x&f(x)\\\hline
1&20\\\hline2&28\\\hline3&40\\\hline4&55\\\hline5&72\\\hline\vdots&\vdots\\\hline10&100\\\hline\vdots&\vdots\\\hline20&165\\\hline
\end{array}$$
All values can be changed in boundaries of $+/-$ their key if it's neccessary.

Comment: You can make the sequence takes any value, according to the Lagrange Polynomial (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plot of the table entries (red line) looks as follows:

[image]

The blue line depicts a linear interpolation.

$$y = 7.490 x + 20.419$$

I took a second order polynomial and minimized the sum of squared errors. This resulted in the linear estimate shown above. The quadratic term vanished.

Comment: +1 interesting, I wonder why linear interpolate works in this case.

Comment: Thank u very much! I thought that this should be second degree function, but it's interesting that it's linear. I only slightly adjusted the initial value.
I'm sorry for so simple question, there is some mess with my head nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many such functions.

One example is $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,10,20\}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}20 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=1
\\28\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=2
\\40\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=3
\\55\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=4
\\72\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=5
\\100\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=10
\\165\,\,\,\,\,\mbox{ if } x=20
\end{cases}$$

If instead you want polynomials you can use [Lagrange interpolating polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Notice that you can create infinitely many satisfying polynomials by interpolation using the seven given points and an arbitrary eighth point (provided the $x$ value of this eighth point is not already taken).

Comment: Though piecewise functions are perfectly legitimate, I'm not sure if they're what OP had in mind...

Comment: @Newb I agree - I just wanted to make it apparent that there are many functions and many types of functions which satisfy the given requirements.